# Connection leakage issue Weblogic

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, weblogic, connection-pooling, database-performance

In our DB we found that the inactive session count was high in GV$Session. But while monitoring the connection pools in weblogic server didn't find as many connections as indicate in the DB.

Checked the application code for the connection leakages but couldnt find any. Can you please help me indicating were might be the problem here.

Weblogic 8.1,
Oracle 10g

Answer (score 0):

Are you running in a Weblogic cluster?

Remember that each Managed Server opens the configured number of connections to the database, so if you've got a count of 10 JDBC connections and 4 managed servers, it's 40 open sessions.

Then do you have multiple pools configured to the same DB using the same credentials, you'll have to total all of those up for each managed server.

Comment: Yes we have a cluster environment and yes multiple pools are configured. I have added together connection pool count from all the managed servers but still there is  mismatch. DB inactive sesssion count is very high

Answer (score 0):

please count the number of max connections allowed for each JDBC in your connection settings.
then check mappings of each JDBC to each server.

When your application runs, the weblogic server creates connections to the DB, after user, instead of disconnecting, it leaves it as an inactive session. thus easy to re-use for weblogic. this number increases to max number allowed as more and more load is put on the application.

the JVM starts giving error once this number for one JDBC is exceeded.

but the connections are not lost, they are inactive. Tally this count against the one you have got.

i suppose they will be same. in such a case, tune your application to reduce connection time and also try better connection logic if available on the web.